# how subtraction of two strlen() function works

Tags: c

Why does the shorter string (`"paid"`) get printed by this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[] = "paid", t[] = "paviDboss";
    if ((strlen(s) - strlen(t)) > 0)
        printf("%s\n", s);
    else
        printf("%s\n", t);
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `main` does not return anything.

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned so the difference cannot be < 0.

Comment: @Osiris `main` does not have to explicitly return anything, it is the only function returning a value that is exempt.

Comment: @WeatherVane You are right, i did not know that.

Comment: @WeatherVane in fact it can be signed too, if `size_t` has conversion rank less than `int`...

Comment: if i print (strlen(s)-strlen(t)) then i wil get -5 so its returning ant int value

Comment: @Pavi that depends oh *how* you print it. Which format specifier? If for example you used `%d` then `printf` *believes* what you tell it. You should use `%zu` for a `size_t` type.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala can you cite that? I can only find in C11 "7.19 2 The types are . . . **size_t** which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator;"

Comment: @WeatherVane I mean that the result of the subtraction can be signed if `size_t` maps to say `unsigned short`, and all of values of `unsigned short` are representable in an `int` then that's where the integer promotions take them to. Nothing in the C standard says that it cannot be `unsigned short` - on the contrary, the only thing that is said is that it shouldn't be greater than `unsigned long` *except when necessary*.

Comment: @weathervane: right; nothing requires `size_t` to be as wide as an `int`. And if it is narrower, integer promotion of the operands to the subtraction will convert it to an `int`, not an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala promoting `unsigned short` to `int` does not make `size_t` negative, although a difference can be. How does that help OP understand his problem?

Comment: The strictly correct answer, I think, is because the two strings are not the same length. Unless you have a very unusual compiler, your `if` statement is checking whether an unsigned integer is greater than zero. It certainly isn't going to be less.

Comment: One thing wrong with the code is that it doesn't `#include <string.h>` so `strlen()` is an undeclared function.  C99 and beyond says that isn't allowed; older versions of C interpreted the function name as a function returning `int`.  However, the result you claim is not consistent with this — what warnings did your compiler give?

Answer (score 7):

Return type of `strlen` is `size_t` which is an unsigned type. The result of the subtraction is also `size_t` and can therefore only be positive.

Just use

```
if(strlen(s) > strlen(t))
```

Comment: Yeah i knw this will work but i have to know why -5>0 condition is not working

Comment: @Pavi As said since the type is unsigned the result of the subtraction can not be negative. Unsigned ints can only be in range of `0` to `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @Pavi Because you don't actually have -5 on the left side.  You probably have 2^64 - 5 due to the result being unsigned.

Comment: this is not `UINT_MAX` here but `SIZE_MAX`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes it should be `size_t` instead of `unsigned int` and `SIZE_MAX` instead of `UINT_MAX`.