# condition is false but even then its printing size of s

Tags: c, pointers, strlen

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printlen(char *s,char *t){
    int c=0;
    int len=((strlen(s)-strlen(t)>c)?strlen(s):strlen(t));
    printf("%d",len);
}

void main(){

char *x="abc";
char *y="defgh";
   printlen(x,y);

}
```

`strlen(s)` is 3 and `strlen(t)` is 5, so why is `strlen(s)-strlen(t)>c` evaluating to true?

Comment: Read the parentheses as `if`. Read the question mark as `then`. Read the colon as `else`. So `((strlen(s)-strlen(t)>c)?strlen(s):strlen(t))` evaluates to "if (strlen(s)-strlen(t)>0) then strlen(s) else strlen(t)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52082709/1216776

Comment: You would do better to reorganize the condition to `(strlen(s) > strlen(t))`, or if `c` might not be zero, then `(strlen(s) > strlen(t) + c)`.  Avoid subtracting unsigned quantities.

Comment: See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/15168)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strlen` function returns a value of type `size_t` which is unsigned.

So subtracting unsigned 3 from unsigned 5 results in a very large unsigned number.  This number is greater than 0 so the condition is true, causing `strlen(s)` to be evaluated and assigned to `len`.

The result of the subtraction should be cast to `int` to properly store a signed value.

```
int len=(((int)(strlen(s)-strlen(t))>c)?strlen(s):strlen(t));
```

Better yet, cast the result of each `strlen` to avoid an out-of-range conversion from unsigned to signed which is implementation defined:

```
int len= ((int)strlen(s)-(int)strlen(t))>c)?strlen(s):strlen(t);
```

Comment: Or `ssize_t`, depending on what range of lengths are expected (in practice, `int` is probably fine).

Comment: @rakeshpatel Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: Conversion of a value out of the `int` range to `int` is implementation-defined. `(int) strlen(s) - (int) strlen(t)` would be preferred over `(int) (strlen(s) - strlen(t))` because the former would have implementation-defined behavior only in the rare cases where one string length exceeds the `int` range, whereas the latter has implementation-defined behavior in the common case that `s` is shorter than `t` (as well as when the difference between string lengths exceeds the `int` range).

Comment: Likely better would be `strlen(s) > strlen(t) + c`, which has problems only when `strlen(t)` + `c` exceeds the range of `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```c
int len=((strlen(s)-(int)strlen(t)>c)?strlen(s):strlen(t));
printf("%d",len);
```

is equal:

```c
int len;

if((strlen(s) - strlen(t) > c)
    len = strlen(s);
else
    len = strlen(t);
printf("%d",len);
```

Firstly, `printf("%d",len);` is unconditional. Whatever `len(s) - strlen(t) > c` is `true` or `false`, `printf("%d",len);` get executed.

Second, `strlen` return `size_t`, which is an alias for `unsigned long long`, so `(strlen(s) - strlen(t) > c)` is always `true`.

You should typecast it to an `int`

`int len=(((int)strlen(s)-(int)strlen(t)>c)?strlen(s):strlen(t));`

Comment: `size_t` is generally not an `unsigned int`.  It usually has a larger type, typically `unsigned long long`.

Comment: `(int)strlen(s)-strlen(t)` is useless. Because `size_t` is unsigned and almost always at leas as wide as `int`, the `-` operator will convert `(int)strlen(s)` to `size_t`, and the result will be unsigned.